# Returning more than one row crashes on PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql, crash

on PostgreSQL I implemented the following stored procedure in C:

```
extern "C" DLLEXPORT Datum
selectServeralRows(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    FuncCallContext     *funcctx;
    int                  call_cntr;
    int                  max_calls;
    TupleDesc            tupdesc;
    AttInMetadata       *attinmeta;

    /* stuff done only on the first call of the function */
    if (SRF_IS_FIRSTCALL())
    {
        MemoryContext   oldcontext;

        /* create a function context for cross-call persistence */
        funcctx = SRF_FIRSTCALL_INIT();

        /* switch to memory context appropriate for multiple function calls */
        oldcontext = MemoryContextSwitchTo(funcctx->multi_call_memory_ctx);

        /* total number of tuples to be returned */
        funcctx->max_calls = 1;

        /* Build a tuple descriptor for our result type */
        if (get_call_result_type(fcinfo, NULL, &tupdesc) != TYPEFUNC_COMPOSITE)
            ereport(ERROR,
                    (errcode(ERRCODE_FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED),
                     errmsg("function returning record called in context "
                        "that cannot accept type record")));

        /*
         * generate attribute metadata needed later to produce tuples from raw
         * C strings
         */
        attinmeta = TupleDescGetAttInMetadata(tupdesc);
        funcctx->attinmeta = attinmeta;

        MemoryContextSwitchTo(oldcontext);
    }

    /* stuff done on every call of the function */
    funcctx = SRF_PERCALL_SETUP();

    if (funcctx->call_cntr < funcctx->max_calls)    /* do when there is more left to send */
    {
        Datum* val = (Datum*)palloc(2 * sizeof(Datum));
        HeapTuple    tuple;
        Datum        result;
        bool    nulls[2]={false,false};

        char * n = new char[2]; 
        n[0] = '1';
        n[1] = '\0';
        char * m = new char[2];
        m[0] = '2';
        n[1] = '\0';

        val[0] = CStringGetTextDatum(m);
        val[1] = CStringGetTextDatum(n);

        /* build a tuple */
        tuple = heap_form_tuple(tupdesc, val, nulls);

        /* make the tuple into a datum */
        result = TupleGetDatum(funcctx->slot, tuple);

        /* clean up (this is not really necessary) */

       SRF_RETURN_NEXT(funcctx, result);
    }
else
       SRF_RETURN_DONE(funcctx);
}
```

The code is almost the same as here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/xfunc-c.html

If the procedure return just one row everything is fine and a table with one row is as desired. But if one line is changed like this

```
/* total number of tuples to be returned */
funcctx->max_calls = 2;
```

the execution of the query crashes with this message:

> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
>   Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x000000000000041a
>   0x0000000100002d8b in heap_form_tuple ()

Stepping through the code shows that nothing until the crash is an invalid pointer so I am a bit clueless. Is there anything else which I have overseen?

EDIT:
The function is called like this in psql:

```
select (selectServeralRows()).*
```

EDIT:
SQL Definition of the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectServeralRows()
RETURNS TABLE(k character varying(20), j character varying(20)) AS
'/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/Debug/libSeveralRows', 'selectServeralRows'
LANGUAGE c STABLE STRICT;
```

Comment: Note: there is no new operator in C.

Comment: I see a bug in line:   Datum* val = (Datum*)palloc(2 + sizeof(Datum)); probably you would to use * instead +

Comment: @wildplasser, actually this is compiled with gcc. Nevertheless I changed it to use malloc and it had the same effect.

Comment: @PavelStehule Thanks. I changed that one too, but it didn't help at the end.

Comment: Why don't you use palloc insted of malloc? BTW: the `palloc(2 + sizeof(Datum));` looks suspect, too.

Comment: @wildplasser as stated above I changed the line to `palloc(2*sizeof(Datum))` which didn't help. I also tried to use palloc instead of malloc: same behaviour.

Comment: I think Datum is intended as an "opaque" type. Wat is the purpose of val. does it serve to return an entire tuple of data?

Comment: I guess that depends on the function one finally uses to create the returning tuple like TupleGetDatum or BuildTupleFromCStrings. I used BuildTupleFromCStrings in the first place but I want to return a binary string. So there are one or more occurrences of '\0', so the string is not passed back properly. Thats why I used this approach which works fine for **one** row but not for more.

Comment: next typical mistake is wrong registration on SQL level - so recheck CREATE FUNCTION statement. Sometimes when I found a "mysterious" bug, I starting from scratch and use some postgres code as base. Try to look on regexp_split_to_table function.

Comment: It appears you are omitting a `tuple = BuildTupleFromCStrings(attinmeta, values);` call before the TupleGetDatum() call.

Comment: @PavelStehule thats what I already did several times and now wanted ask somebody else. @wildplasser thats why I use val and make tuple out of it `tuple = heap_form_tuple(tupdesc, val, nulls);`

Comment: Yes, but at that point, tupdesc is uninitialised (exept in the 1st call) Voila!

Comment: Voila! Thank you both very much!

Comment: I'll clone my comments into an answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have omitted a

```
 tuple = BuildTupleFromCStrings(funcctx->attinmeta, val);
```

call before the `TupleGetDatum(...)` call. The tuple variable is still uninitialised, except on the first call.

Also, `Datum* val = (Datum*)palloc(2 * sizeof(Datum));` should probably be

```
char **val;
val = palloc (2 * sizeof *val);
```

And the n and m arrays could just as well be;

```
char n[2] ="1", m[2] = "2";
val[0] = n;
val[1] = m;
```

And you can free the memory *after the call* to `heap_form_tuple(tupdesc, val, nulls);`

```
pfree(val);
```

IMHO 'val' could also be an automatic ("stack") variable, just like n[] and m[].